# How to program MIDI (Musical Instrument Digital Interface) applications?

Tags: c#, java, c++, midi, javasound

I want to start programming [MIDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDI) applications. As I have never programmed any MIDI applications in the past, I need to know where to start. First of all, what language should I choose so that I can research its available MIDI APIs. Should it be C++, C#, Java etc.? I know that all of the "big" companies are mostly coding in C++ their MIDI applications, but is C++ becoming a language of the past, and is it worth spending time to learn its MIDI APIs?

Thank you

Comment: C++ is not by any means a "language of the past", and is not in any danger of becoming so any time soon.

Comment: What language do you have the most experience in?  That's probably a bigger factor in deciding on a language for a project.

Comment: Voted to close, but note that [Java Sound](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) is Java's inbuilt support for MIDI.

Comment: Thank you for your replies guys, they are definitely helpful. I have a lot of experience in Java and C#. I apologize if I have hurt anyone with my question, and the phrase "language of the past". Still, I truly do not believe that this is a legitimate reason to close my topic.

Answer (score 2):

> First of all, what language should I choose so that I can research its
>   available MIDI APIs. Should it be C++, C#, Java etc.?

Choose the language which you prefer and in which you are comfortable with.

> but is C++ becoming a language of the past, and is it worth spending
>   time to learn its MIDI APIs?

Nobody on earth can say that C++ is a language of the past.

Check the reference on [MIDI Package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/overview-MIDI.html) and [Understanding and using Java MIDI audio](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/it/it-0801art38/)

For C++ you can refer [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1884777449).